# MAMP suddenly stopped working due to a ports and/or server issue Windows

Tags: error-handling, mamp

I downloaded MAMP, but when I run it fails on connecting to a port. So the error is about the port 80 (can se the error on the link below). I did what most forums reecomend: set port config to default but it still does not work. Instead inmeadiately after I click accept to make the changes the program  suddenly stops running (see the link to the image below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCEex.png
(The last window is in Spanish but it's simple to see it says something went wrong, does not explain what and forces to close the program)

I don't what can it be, I am not an expert on this topic so I feel a bit confused since I've tried almost everything . I'm starting to think it may be a limitation of my pc since it is a bit old, or maybe i'm just missing something.

Comment: Your question is unclear, there is a lot of information that are not relevant to the question's understanding it self. Please read the following guide to how to make a good question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please check the rules (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to post your question: include short fragments of your code/scripts, show the bug in your report and tell us what the expected behavior is/was. Also, be precise about versions, updates and the software you are using, but focus on what is relevant.

Comment: thanks for the review, already modified the question